# Android4.3 (KitKat / Using Chromium WebView) How Do I Listen to onfocus DOM Event on a WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, events, contenteditable, copy-paste

I have searched almost everywhere on the internet without an apparent solution.

I have a native Android application that has a `contentEditable` WebView.
(*which has an initial sample HTML with some formatting and a few images in it*)

Currently, when the user pastes something we have a few problems

- First of all, Android does not honor the caret position: When a sample text is pasted to the bottom of the `contentEditable` div; it gets pasted at the beginning instead.
- The same thing happens in test autosuggestion too: When the user chooses something from the autosuggest list in the middle of the editable content, the suggestion is pasted to the beginning of the content instead.

Here are my further findings:

- `onpaste` event does not fire (*which is the most obvious way to detect if something is pasted*)
- I tried using [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver); although they worked on Desktop Chrome, I got an "object not defined" error when I tried it on the device.
- When content is pasted only `keyup`, `input`, and `keydown` events are being fired. (*I attached to [any possible event I can think of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events) they were the only ones that work.

Moreover:

- When the user pastes something, I get a `keydown` event followed by an `input` event;
- When the user types something, I get a sequence of `keydown` `input` `keyup` events;
- And when the user autocorrects something, I get a N consecutive `input` events (***N*** being a random number between 1 and 5, as per my observations are concerned).

(*note that no **keyup** event is fired after a paste, or an autosuggest action*)

Given these constraints, my only feasable solution was to

1. Cache the current `selectionRange` (*in order to cache the caret position*) whenever the user taps the screen, or types something;
2. Cache the `innerHTML` of the `contentEditable` area at every keypress;
3. When an `input` event is fired, set a `100ms` timer to check if it's followed by a `keyup` event.

   - If it is, then do nothing since it's regular type event
   - If it's not, then

     1. Do a **diff/merge** between the cached `innerHTML` and the current `innerHTML`;
     2. Extract the **pasted content** from that "diff/merge";
     3. Restore the `contentEditable`'s `innerHTML` to the **cached** value;
     4. Insert the extracted pasted content to the cached caret position;
     5. Move the caret to the end of the inserted content above.

This algorithm (*although works in theory*) is hacky as hell.

Does anyone have bumped into a similar issue? I'll desperately appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I think I'll work on it and publish as an open-source projects. Looks like a challenging and fun task. -- Any pointers are greatly appreciated though.